# How to overcome the random failing of my selenium webdriver-java script?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Currently, i am running my selenium  webdriver - java scripts, there is a strange issue which is cropping up these days. My scripts run absoulutely fine and when I re-run them.. sometimes my scripts enter the values via sendkeys() in some other fields as a result of which my entire script fails.

I dont know the real reason behind it, I know the scripts what i am running are pretty simple and straight flows.. Is this because of my application response issue? Because I have given wait commands also to tackle the same.But when I have re-run the same scripts again it enters the values in some irrelevant fields..

Note: I dont change any of my codes while rerunning it... Its more frustrating
Is this normal when you run Selenium webdriver-java scripts??

Please advise me how to tackle this issue because I am not aware to deal with this issue

Answer (score 0):

You might need to figure out if your elements locators are changing dynamically each time you run and then look at your code locators to be more appropriately handling the change.   Other than that I see no reason why the elements being interacted with, change randomly.

Comment: I understood your point.. but the locators what i am detecting in my scripts dont change dynamically.. I have verified the same.. Even after that my scripts are failing Kindly advise

Comment: Can you paste a bit of your code and your html or a public site where this can be replicated.  Probably it can help debug your issue.